# Matlab 3D Plot (surf) fills in empty gaps automatically

Tags: matlab

I'm using `surf()` to plot a portion of a sphere; basically a shell of a certain shape that is on top of a sphere.  More specifically, it is the workspace plot of spherical joint with color representing the resolution of the joint at that point.

Anyways, the shape is unique, but `surf()` automatically fills in gaps that should not be there.  I'm guess it might be the order that it is plotted?  Is there any way to prevent Matlab from doing this?

I think it is obvious in the pictures what should not be there:

[image: first picture]

[image]

Also, it seems to mess up the color coding as well.  The dark blue should be at the bottom edges of the shell; instead Matlab assigns it to the surface used to fill the gaps.

Comment: would you mind to post what you have done up to now in terms of code?

Answer (score 1):

The following code achieves what I think you are asking (namely - making part of a surface plot "invisible", which I do by defining a matrix `transp` of the same dimensions as `zz`, with alpha values (1=visible, 0=transparent). Of course you will have to change your definition of `transp` to match the parts of the surface you don't want to see - my simple clipping method is just to show what can be done):

```
[xx yy]=meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,200));
zz = 1./(xx.^2 + yy.^2 + 0.5);
theta = atan2(yy,xx);
r = sqrt(xx.^2 + yy.^2);
transp = double(r < (0.3*cos(6*theta)+0.6));
figure
surf(xx,yy,zz,'edgecolor','none','FaceAlpha', 'interp', 'AlphaData', transp);
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

I trust you can figure it out from here. If this doesn't work you need to give more information about the data you have - what is the size, how are you plotting it...